# What is "class multiplication" in group theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading chapter 2 of Tinkham's *Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics* and am completely baffled by his Chapter 2-9, and perhaps that's because the terminology/notation seems so ancient. I've attached the relevant passage at the end, but essentially, letting $G_i$ denote an arbitrary conjugacy class of some group $G$, Tinkham writes a formula like
$$G_iG_j = \sum_k c_{ijk}G_k.$$
Now I suppose the left-hand side I can interpret as a product of subsets, but the right-hand side? What could the "addition" of subsets mean? If anyone has a reference which makes this all more rigorous I would really appreciate it.

The one illegible bit in the below should read $\mathscr{R}=\mathscr{H}$. Tinkham also seems weirdly to be referring to some multiset type of structure even though "classes" were defined earlier as conjugacy classes (sets).

[image]

Comment: I don't have my copy of Tinkham off-hand, and I haven't gone through it in quite some time, but I think your comment about multisets is spot on.  Interpret the left-hand side as the multiset of elements you get by multiplying all the elements of $G_i$ by all the elements in $G_j$.  You necessarily get a multiset that as full copies of conjugacy classes (by the converse theorem mentioned).

Comment: Then, the sum is just a formal way of writing this multiset: $c_{ijk}C_k$ says that there are $c_{ijk}$ copies of $C_k$ in the multiset.

Comment: Have you heard of the [group algebra](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html)? This is a similar construction called the algebra of classes.

Comment: Agree with @NiharKarve. This surely looks like a product of elements in the group algebra. Actually the group ring $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ suffices here. It is a standard fact that sums of elements of a conjugate class form a basis of the center of the group ring. There the product of two class sums is a $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combination of class sums.

Comment: @NiharKarve I know what an algebra is, but that involves defining products of vectors in a vector space. It's not clear to me what a group algebra would then mean even after reading your link...how do I define the sum of subsets here?

Comment: Feedback, whether negative or positive, is appreciated @EE18

Comment: For example, when $G=S_3$ you have three sums of conjugate classes in the group algebra $\Bbb{C}[S_3]$: $G_1=1$, $G_2=(12)+(13)+(23)$ and $G_3=(123)+(132)$. A non-trivial product is
$$G_2G_3=(12)(123)+(12)(132)+(13)(123)+(13)(132)+(23)(123)+(23)(132)=2G_2.$$
As you can easily check, each 2-cycle appears among the six terms exactly twice. That's all there is to it. As an exercise, show that $G_2G_2=3G_1+3G_3$, and $G_3G_3=2G_1+G_3$.

Comment: Don't think of the group algebra being something you have seen earlier. It is something created for this very purpose (a bookkeeping device in a sense) . That is, tracking linear combinations of the ways the elements of a group act in a (linear) representation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for that, that definitely gets me closer to understanding. I'm afraid I still don't understand. I'm used to writing $G_2=\{(12),(13),(23)\}$ but am not sure what the addition means. I get that it's addition of elements from the conjugacy class, but how do I define addition of permutations here? Would it be possible to write an answer including the exact definition of the algebraic structure?

Comment: Do reread the description of the group algebra! The elements are simply (formal) linear combinations (usually with complex coefficients) of elements of the group. The addition $(12)+(13)+(23)$ does not "mean" anything else. It may be helpful to think of the group algebra of $S_3$ as simply a 6-dimensional vector space (here $6=|S_3|$), but rather than being indexed by $1,2,3,4,5,6$ the components are indexed by the elements of the group. So if we use the ordering $1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)$ for the six elements of $S_3$, then $(12)+(13)+(23)$ becomes $(0,1,1,1,0,0)$.

Comment: (cont'd) The group operation (so in the case of $S_3$ the composition of permutations) then defines a multiplication for the vectors in a natural basis (one component equal to $1$, the rest all zeros). And we can "extend that multiplication bilinearly" to get a multiplication rules for all the vectors in the group algebra.

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I now understand the structure of a group algebra. But are you saying there's no connection to the notion of a multiset here (as alluded to by Tinkham)?

Comment: Each multiset of group elements corresponds naturally to an element of the group algebra (using the multiplicities as coefficients).

Comment: @JBL Would you be able to flesh this out as an answer? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @EE18 Linear combinations of elements just mean "I have 2 of this, 3 of that", i.e. multisets, nothing more. Let's say you have a group $\{apple, banana\}$, with $apple$ being neutral and $banana \times banana = apple$. (So this is just $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, +)$, but that's clearer if avoiding numbers, because numbers are already used to count elements). Then $\{apple, banana, banana\} \times \{apple, banana\} \\= \{apple, banana, banana, banana, apple, apple \}$ $(1 \;apple + 2 \; banana) \times (1 \; apple + 1 \; banana) = 3 \; apple + 3 \; banana$.

Comment: The multiset consisting of two copies of $(12)$ and three copies of $(132)$ corresponds to the group algebra element $2(12) + 3(132)$.  The "formal sum" he's talking about is literally just the disjoint union of multisets (where the coefficients $c_{ijk}$ are the multiplicities).

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Although in the present context multisets would suffice, the group algebra (or the group ring) also has elements like $2\ apple-3\ banana$. And, if/when needed $i\ apple +\sqrt7\ banana$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this a little more carefully by doing the following.  Define the group ring of the group over the integers by taking all formal linear combinations of the group elements with integer coefficients. That is, an element of the group ring is given by
$$
\sum_jn_jg_j
\,,
$$
where $j$ runs over the group elements $g_j$ and $n_j\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Addition of elements in this ring is given by
$$
\sum_jn_jg_j+\sum_jm_jg_j = \sum_j(n_j+m_j)g_j
\,,
$$
and multiplication is given by
$$
\left(\sum_in_ig_i\right)\left(\sum_jm_jg_j\right) = \sum_{i,j}(n_jm_j)(g_ig_j)
\,,
$$
where the products in parentheses are the normal products in the respective algebraic structures (multiplication of integers and multiplication of elements in the group, respectively). Finally, (integer) scalar multiplication via
$$
m\sum_jn_jg_j = \sum_j(mn_j)g_j\,,
$$
makes this into a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Now, consider a set of special elements of the group ring,
$$
\mathcal{C}_j=\sum_{g\in C_j}g\,,
$$
where $C_j$ is a conjugacy class of the group.  This element *uniquely* corresponds to the conjugacy class in the sense that we can interpret the expansion $\sum_in_ig_i$ as "counting" the number $n_i$ of times $g_i$ shows up in a multiset of elements of $G$. This element is in the *center* of the group ring, and in fact the collection of $\mathcal{C}_j$'s is a *basis* for the center of the group ring (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3852078/852914)). For instance, since $g^{-1}C_jg=C_j$, we can easily see that
$$
g^{-1}\mathcal{C}_jg = g^{-1}\left(\sum_{h\in C_j}h\right)g
=
\sum_{h\in C_j}g^{-1}hg
=\sum_{ghg^{-1} \in C_j} h
=\sum_{h \in C_j}h
=
\mathcal{C_j}\,,
$$
and therefore any formal $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of elements of the group will commute with $\mathcal{C_j}$.

Suppose that we multiply two of these elements $\mathcal{C}_j$ by each other. Since
$$
g^{-1}\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_jg
=
g^{-1}\mathcal{C}_igg^{-1}\mathcal{C}_jg
=\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j\,,
$$
which means that $\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j$ is in the center of the group ring. As such, it can be expanded as an integer linear combination of the $\mathcal{C}_i$'s. Finally, we can make contact with the notation from Tinkham:

We then have that
$$
\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j = \sum_ka_{ijk}\mathcal{C}_k\,.
$$
for some coefficients $a_{ijk}$ since the $\mathcal{C}_k$ are a basis of the center of the group ring (in which $\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j$ resides).

Our goal is to explain why $a_{ijk} = c_{ijk}$, where the $c$'s are defined in the excerpt from Tinkham in the OP as "the integer telling how often the complete class $\mathcal{C}_k$ appears in the product $\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j$".

By explicitly computing the product in the algebra, we get
$$
\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j
=
\left(\sum_{g\in C_i}g\right)\left(\sum_{h\in C_j}h\right)
=
\sum_{g\in C_i,h\in C_j}gh\,.
$$
If we expand out this double sum, we can see that each product of one element from $C_i$ and one element from $C_j$ shows up exactly once, and so we get exactly the (multi-)set of elements arrived at by multiplying the conjugacy classes $C_i$ and $C_j$, interpreted as a formal sum.  Because of that, we can rearrange the sum as
$$
\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j
=
\sum_{k}c_{ijk}\mathcal{C}_k
\,,
$$
thereby arriving at Tinkham's formal expression for the product of conjugacy classes expanded as a "sum" of conjugacy classes.

---

Here is an example, using the symmetric group $S_3$ on three elements. A conjugacy class in a symmetric group is made up of all elements with the same cycle structure, so for $S_3$, we have
$$
C_0 = {e}\,,~~~~~~C_1={(12),(23),(13)}\,,~~~~~~C_2 = {(123),(132)}\,.
$$
Let's form the special formal linear combinations of the elements from these conjugacy classes, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal{C}_0 = e\,,~~~~~~\mathcal{C}_1=(12)+(23)+(13)\,,~~~~~~\mathcal{C}_2 = (123)+(132)\,.
$$
Now, we multiply these elements. (We have to choose a convention for cycle multiplication: we will choose the one in which the permutation on the left is performed first.) The result is
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}_0\mathcal{C}_0 &= (e)\cdot(2)
=
e
\\&=\mathcal{C}_0
\,,\\
\mathcal{C}_0\mathcal{C}_1 &= (e)\cdot((12)+(23)+(13))
=
(12)+(23)+(13)
\\&=\mathcal{C}_1
\,,\\
\mathcal{C}_0\mathcal{C}_2 &= (e)\cdot((123)+(132))
=
(123)+(132)
\\&=\mathcal{C}_2
\,,\\
\mathcal{C}_1\mathcal{C}_1 &= ((12)+(23)+(13))\cdot((12)+(23)+(13))
\\
&=
(12)(12)+(12)(23)+(12)(13)
+(23)(12)+(23)(23)+(23)(13)
\\&\qquad\mbox{}
+(13)(12)+(13)(23)+(13)(13)
\\&=
e+(132)+(123)+(231)+e+(213)+(132)+(123)+e
\\&=3e + 3(132)+3(123)
\\&=3\mathcal{C}_0+3\mathcal{C}_2\,,
\\
\mathcal{C}_1\mathcal{C}_2 &=
((12)+(23)+(13))\cdot((123)+(132))
\\&=
(12)(123)+(12)(132)+
(23)(123)+(23)(132)+
(13)(123)+(13)(132)+
\\&=
(13) + (23) + (21) + (31) + (23) + (12)
\\&=
2(12) + 2(13) + 2(23)
\\&=
2\mathcal{C}_1\,,
\\
\mathcal{C}_2\mathcal{C}_2
&=
((123)+(132))\cdot((123)+(132))
\\&=
(123)(123)+(123)(132)+(132)(123)+(132)(132)
\\&=
(132) + e + e + (123)
\\&=
2\mathcal{C}_0 + 2\mathcal{C}_2\,.
\end{align}
Through this exhaustive calculation, we can see that on each penultimate line, we have a list of elements that break up naturally into full copies of conjugacy classes. The ``addition'' here is really just the same as a disjoint union of copies of the conjugacy classes.  Alternatively, these can be written as mulitsets.  But this representation in terms of an *algebra* really captures the important information, allows us to represent the info in a nice notational way, and allows us to use algebra to make further conclusions.

Comment: This is a good description, but near the end it would be good to mention that the result of the double sum is invariant under conjugation by any element of $G$, acting on the group ring in the natural way, so that the result can indeed be decomposed as a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of conjugacy classes.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I believe that is mentioned in the excerpt from the book shown in the OP (proofs are in two different parenthetical in the excerpt), but I can add that in.  Part of that follows directly from the fact that the conjugacy classes form a basis for the center of the ring, but I can show that explicitly.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I've made some edits to the post. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: I am going to take some time to digest this answer and will get back to you. Thank you for supplying it.

Comment: First question: when you write "any formal $\mathbb{Z}$
-linear combination of elements of the group will commute with $\mathcal{C_j}$", does that follow because the equation below that sentence can be multiplied through by $g$ to have that conclusion for each term of such a linear combination?

Comment: Second question: Is it correct to understand from your answer that the crucial step is to define an isomorphism between the set of multisets of $G$ and the group ring you define here? It seems this is what you do in the beginning in identifying the conjugacy classes with an element of the group ring, and then at the end by identifying the expanded product with a multiset. If this is so, what I don't follow is why we expect that on the RHS of $\mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j
=
\left(\sum_{g\in C_i}g\right)\left(\sum_{h\in C_j}h\right)
=
\sum_{g\in C_i,h\in C_j}gh\,$ we expect that there...

Comment: ...should be exactly the same number $c_{ijk}$ of each element of a given conjugacy class (using the isomorphism to identify with a formal sum) $\mathcal{C}_k$ in this expanded product. That is, if there are two occurrences of $g_k$ in $\sum_{g\in C_i,h\in C_j}gh\,$ then why must there also be 2 occurences of $g'_k$ therein? I see how this is necessary from $\mathcal{C}_k$ spanning the center of the group ring, but not how the explicit product leads to this conclusion.

Comment: Finally, I assume that this whole discussion is restricted to finite groups, right? Thank you once again for this incredible answer. I will accept and award the points either way, but if you can answer any of my follow-up questions I would really appreciate it.

Comment: For the first question, I think you've got it: thinking of $g$ as an element of the group ring, you can pass it through the sum (on either side) so that it hits $\mathcal{C_j}$, thereby making $g\mathcal{C_j}=\mathcal{C_j}g$ (since $g\mathcal{C_j}g^{-1}=\mathcal{C_j}$ and then passing it out of the sum on the other side.

Comment: For the second, I was hoping that this would be clear from the notation. To make the multiset that is the product of conjugacy classes, you take each element of $C_i$ and multiply it by each element of $C_j$. *That is exactly what the product of $\mathcal{C_i}\mathcal{C_j}$ does!* - look carefully at the double sum, and you'll see that. Alternatively, look at the example I did for $S_3$, and I think you can convince yourself that each of those calculations is essentially the same as just multiplying all elements of ${C}_i$ by all elements of ${C}_j$, keeping track of the number of repetitions.

Comment: And yes, I think this really only works for finite groups. (I'm not sure how you would define the infinite sum of elements of an infinite conjugacy class!) Apparently, the properties of group rings for infinite groups is an active area of research. @EE18

Comment: @EE18 Also, I forgot to @ you on the previous comments.

Comment: Superb, thank you on all fronts!

Comment: Also, can I ask just once more to confirm: it is fair to say that the underlying structure here is some isomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{A}_G \to \mathbb{Z}[G]$ (where $\mathcal{A}_G$ is the set of all multisets of $G$) defined by $\phi(A) = \sum_{g_i \in A} n_ig_i$ where $n_i$ is the multiplicity of $g_i \in A$. Then the line I am confused about says that $\phi(C_iC_j) = \phi(C_i)\phi(C_j) \equiv \mathcal{C}_i\mathcal{C}_j$ where we define the product of multisets $C_iC_j$ by analogy to how we define the product of arbitrary subsets in elementary group theory?

Comment: @EE18 I *think* there is an isomorphism *of sets* $\mathcal{A}_G\to\mathbb{Z}[G]$, but there is not a multiplication defined on the multisets, so $\mathcal{C_iC_j}$ doesn't make sense, and $\phi$ is not an isomorphism of groups/rings.  Or rather, the way to define the multiplication *is exactly the way we've done it* in the group ring.  The multiplication on the multisets doesn't come first. (I thought at first that you might be looking for some universal property of the group ring, but the universal property of the group ring is related to algebras and groups of units and not multisets.)

Comment: Why can't we define the multiplication of multisets just like we do the multiplication of sets, except that we retain "duplicate" copies?